# Caliburn Micro reload data on event

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

While handling a CurrentLayoutIdChangedEvent event, the backend sends back the correct data, but the setter for the model is not called and because of this, the UI won't reflect the changes.

Following the usual pattern to setting values in the getter.

The properties:

```
private LayoutModel _layout;
private string _layoutName;

public LayoutModel Layout
{
    get { return _layout; }
    set { _layout = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LayoutName); }
}

public string LayoutName
{
    get { return _layout == null ? "Not set" : _layout.Name; }
    set { _layoutName = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FullArea); }
}
```

The event:

```
public void Handle(CurrentLayoutIdChangedEvent message) => PopulateLayout(message.LayoutId);
```

The function:

```
private void PopulateLayout(int layoutId)
{
    if (layoutId > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            _layout = _dataProvider.GetLayoutById(layoutId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "Invalid Layout returned with '{layoutId}', exiting.", layoutId);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.Error("Invalid LayoutId, aborting.");
    }
}
```

A part of the view:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:Resources.Txt_LayoutName}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="LayoutName" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
</StackPanel>
```

When receiving the event the function is called and the data is loaded into the _layout, but the setter of the public property is not called, so the LayoutName won't change.

Not sure what am I missing, the initial data in the LayoutName ("Not set") is displayed properly.
Tried to introduce a new event after the dataProvider returns the data, which only calls the NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Layout); - also not giving any errors or desired result.

Comment: Where in the XAML is your binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe I understood your concern correctly The Setter of Property `Layout`, in which you are Notifying the property change of `LayoutName` is not called during `PopulateLayout`, because, you are assigning value to the private variable `_layout`. (Not the property `Layout`)

You need to replace following line

```
 _layout = _dataProvider.GetLayoutById(layoutId);
```

with

```
 Layout= _dataProvider.GetLayoutById(layoutId);
```

Or Notify the `LayoutName` from the `PopulateLayout` method

```
_layout = _dataProvider.GetLayoutById(layoutId);
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LayoutName);
```

Comment: Thank you Anu, the first is the better solution for me, since Layout has other properties which needs to know about the model change.